# How do I ImageMapType without duplicate marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

mageMapType problem with marker. They are duplicates. I'm implementing map with custom image. Drag the map to left and right, the markes are duplicates. see example: http://rafaelribeirowebmaster.com.br/zoom/_index.html

Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the default-behaviour of markers, they will be repeated when the map will repeat the "world" in the viewport.

The only option I see is to create the markers by using [custom overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays)(these will not repeat)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I was using the library Elabel. It does something similar, but the problem was on event click. it's not worked, Then I moved the command "overlayLayer.appendChild" to "overlayMouseTarget", but I need centralize the map on point of the custom overlay.

How to do it?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(customOverlay, 'click', function() {
      map.setCenter(customOverlay.getPosition());
})
```

Comment: is this an answer? a new question?

Comment: Sorry, This is also a new question.